# Could not parse value xxx in line xxx, column xxx

Tags: c#, machine-learning, .net-core, ml.net

While trying to get preview data of `IDataView` object, I am getting the following error

**Outer exception**

> System.FormatException: 'Parsing failed with an exception: Could not parse value {some value} in line {number}, column {name of column}'

**Inner Exception**

> InvalidOperationException: Could not parse value {some value} in line {number},
> column {name of column}

*[Here](https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/real-or-fake-fake-jobposting-prediction) is the DataSet I tried to load*

**The Input Model**

```
public class JobPostInput
    {
        [LoadColumn(0)]
        [ColumnName("job_id")]
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(1)]
        [ColumnName("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(2)]
        [ColumnName("location")]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(3)]
        [ColumnName("department")]
        public string Department { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(4)]
        [ColumnName("salary_range")]
        public string SalaryRange { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(5)]
        [ColumnName("company_profile")]
        public string CompanyProfile { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(6)]
        [ColumnName("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(7)]
        [ColumnName("requirements")]
        public string Requirements { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(8)]
        [ColumnName("benefits")]
        public string Benefits { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(9)]
        [ColumnName("telecommuting")]
        public bool Telecommuting { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(10)]
        [ColumnName("has_company_logo")]
        public bool HasCompanyLogo { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(11)]
        [ColumnName("has_questions")]
        public bool HasQuestions { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(12)]
        [ColumnName("employment_type")]
        public string EmployementType { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(13)]
        [ColumnName("required_experience")]
        public string ExperienceRequired { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(14)]
        [ColumnName("required_education")]
        public string RequiredEducation { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(15)]
        [ColumnName("industry")]
        public string Industry { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(16)]
        [ColumnName("function")]
        public string Function { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(17)]
        [ColumnName("fraudulent")]
        public bool IsFraud { get; set; }
    }
```

**Error code**

```
    var dataView = _context.Data.LoadFromTextFile<JobPostInput>(path: "file path", hasHeader: true, separatorChar: ',');
    var preview = dataView.Preview();//exception here
```

**Note:**

1. I'd tried reducing the number of rows in the csv file to 1. Even though the exception is happening.
2. The column name specified in the error is of type `boolean` but the value showing is of type `string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change to your `JobPostInput` should help with this issue.

Change the following properties to use `float` instead of `bool`:

- Telecommuting
- HasCompanyLogo
- HasQuestions
- IsFraud

It's trying to parse those into boolean values but they are actually integers (floats in the case of ML.NET). They can be converted to booleans by using the [`context.Transforms.Conversion.ConvertType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.conversionsextensionscatalog.converttype?view=ml-dotnet) method.

Comment: It helped fix the issue. But did you notice the second point I mentioned in the Note section of my qn? The value ml.net couldn't parse is of some text from another column, not from any of the boolean column. Or is this yet another misleading-error-situation from .net?

Comment: It could be misleading. It loaded for me after I made the `float` changes. Are you still getting errors after making those changes?

Comment: Nope. It got fixed as I said